# ES5 puzzle of private variable defined in constructor

Tags: javascript, closures, ecmascript-5

I am reading the **Private Variable** section in "Professional JavaScript for Web Developers 3rd Edition", and feel puzzled about one of the sample codes:

```
function Person(name) {
  this.setName = function(value) {
    name = value;
  }

  this.getName = function() {
    return name;
  }
}

var person1 = new Person('p1');
person1.setName('p11');
person1.getName();  // 'p11'

var person2 = new Person('p2');
person2.getName();  // 'p2'
```

The `getName()` method accesses the `name` variable via the closure and scope chain, while the `setName()` method assigns a new value to `name`.

#### Question:

Where does the `name` variable exist?

Why does every instance of `Person` have a different `name`, so that if one instance modifies the `name` variable it would not affect other instances?

====================================

I think that every time an instance is created with `new`, there a `Person Activation Object` is being created. The `name` variable in the every `Person Activation Object` is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour has nothing to do with `new`.

Every time you invoke `Person`, a new, separate instance of the parameter variable `name` is created. The code inside that function can access that variable. There is nothing more to it.

This is true for parameter variables in every function you may declare. As long as it is possible to reference such variables they remain in memory -- they are not garbage collected.

Calling `Person` twice, is in essence not much different then calling 2 different functions which both have the same parameters and methods:

```
function Person1(name) {
  this.setName = function(value) {
    name = value;
  }

  this.getName = function() {
    return name;
  }
}

function Person2(name) {
  this.setName = function(value) {
    name = value;
  }

  this.getName = function() {
    return name;
  }
}

var person1 = new Person1('p1');
person1.setName('p11');
person1.getName();  // 'p11'

var person2 = new Person2('p2');
person2.getName();  // 'p2'
```

Of course, here `person1` and `person2` are no longer the instance of the same constructor, but besides that the principle of separate variable instances and scopes is the same.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my grammer errors(my english it not so good. hhh...). Then, I still understand where does the name variable in `setName()` method exist?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "where"? It exists in memory. At each function call, new memory is allocated for the new instance of the `name` parameter. This memory will not be released unless it cannot be accessed anymore. The `setName` method also exists separately for each instance: each `setName` method will access the `name` it can access to. So you can have *n* `setName` methods, each accessing their "own" `name` of which there are also *n*.

Comment: I mean the memory model like [the closure illustrate](https://www.processon.com/view/link/59a0c28ee4b0f5d6e72160ab)

Comment: Well, the scope chain is separate for each instance of `Person`. If you call it *n* times, you will have *n* separate scopes. See addition to my answer.